# Generating Message-ID for mails sent by crond

Tags: email, cron, ssmtp

On my **NixOS** installation I have **Vixie cron** installed, that runs regular jobs. The output for the scripts that are run is sent by e-mail using a **ssmtp** on the same host, that forwards the mails to my standard mail server (**Postfix** with **rspamd**).

My problem now is that most of these mails are stored in my **Spam** folder by the mail server. I checked the classification that is done by the spam filter and saw that one big 'problem' is that the messages sent by cron don't include a **Message-ID** header.

I searched for options to let crond generate message-ids or ssmtp to inject message-ids if they are not present yet (like other MSA can do). For neither of these I found a way to implement that.

What could I do to handle that better and to make sure these administrative mails are not classified as Spam?

Comment: Rather than a "proper" fix, from the sending side, consider the simple solution of adjusting your spam filter and whitelist this specific sender.